# Выборка из BD

Tags: php, запрос, mysql

День добрый.
Натолкните, куда копать. Есть BD, в ней таблица products, в ней колонка products_export, в ней может быть от 1 до 16 чисел (числа не повторяются) в диапазоне (1-16), данные в этой колонке хранятся в формате (1, 3, 4, 5 и т.д.), пользователь передает массив типа:

> $prodExp = product_export[1,4,12,16]

Как выбрать те строки, в которых:

1) есть хотя бы одно совпадение;
 2) есть более 1-го совпадения;
 3) точное совпадение.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/129195/

Answer (score 1):

Ну, точное совпадение сделать сможете, а все остальное через LIKE.